# Host mail server and web application on same server

Tags: docker, mail-server

I've a web application which i've hosted on my VPS server. I've also successfully hosted my mail server ([mailcow](https://mailcow.github.io/mailcow-dockerized-docs/)) on that same server. But the problem is my mail server is replacing my web application. I cannot browse my web application when I run my mail server. Instead of loading my web application it is loading Mailcow UI. Can anyone help me how should I run both of my application and mail server on same IP.

(Please let me know if you need more information.)

Comment: Are you running them with docker-compose ? If so, can you share your docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: Yes, i am running this with docker-composer. That is 635 line long file, where should i put all this code?

Comment: Can you share in https://ideone.com/ ?

Comment: @JohnDoe here is my docker-compose.yml file link: https://codeshare.io/nzlOlj

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the launch of one container is killing another container that is not fully launched .

When I have this kind of problem, I prefer to launch the containers separately using Dockerfile and control the launchs with an orchestrator shell script that use the docker logs of one container to check when it is fully available so that another container can be launched.

Comment: Thanks for your time, But I do not have enough knowledge related to server. I follow youtube tutorials to integrate what i need. So this kind of terminology is unfamiliar to me. Do you have any other way to explain this!

Comment: A docker container is an isolated piece of your OS where you can simulate the running of different OS with different configurations without affecting your host OS. docker-compose is a software to launch containers simultaneously with possible dependency relations . The problem is that a container can launch process in the background after they are launched and sometimes you need some of these process to complete before you launch another container. I don't know about a way to do it with docker-compose. So what I usually do is to write a shell script that controls the launch of the containers

Comment: Thanks for your time again, i was able to solve the problem. I followed the doc from mailcow, the problem was, i wasn't configuring reverse proxy properly, which i did last night. Now everything is working as i wanted.